# How to select element by order ? - Css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In a `div` with class `product`, there are some multi-level elements. These include two images. The first image is the product thumbnail and the second image is the product rating. **They  both don't have class and I can't change the html code.** Sometimes, the images is wrapped inside a `<a></a>`tag.

I have to select the `image product` only. It's the first `img` that appears by order inside each `div.product`.

```html
<html>
    <style>
    img {
    border: solid 2px black 
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="product">
       <a href="#"><img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"></a><br>
       <img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/>     
      </div>
      <div class="product">
       <a href="#"><img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/></a>     
      </div>
      <div class="product">
      <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"><br>
       <a hre="#"><img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/></a> 
      </div>
      <div class="product">
       <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"><br>
       <img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"></img>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried with `first-of-type` and `first-child` but this method ignore children and sub-children. The wrapped image gets ignored. 
How can I do that **without changing the html code**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this...

```css
div.product img[data-pin-nopin="true"]:nth-child(1){
    border-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<style>
  img {
    border: solid 2px black
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="product">
    <a href="#">
      <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true">
    </a>
    <br>
    <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <a href="#">
      <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true">
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true">
    <br>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true" />
    <br>
    <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the first image has property `border`. You can style by that.

```
.product img[border] {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both:

```
div.product > img:last-child {
    border-color: red;  
}
div.product > a:last-child img {
    border-color: red;  
}
```

The first will be applied to the the last-image only if it's a direct child of the `div.product` element.
The second will be applied to the image of the last anchor (also - if it's a direct child of the `div.product` element).

Here is a working example:

```css
img {
  border: solid 2px black 
}
div.product > img:last-child {
  border-color: red;  
}
div.product > a:last-child img {
  border-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <a href="#"><img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"></a><br>
  <img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/>     
</div>
<div class="product">
  <a href="#"><img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"></a><br>
  <a href="#"><img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/></a>     
</div>
<div class="product">
  <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"><br>
  <a hre="#"><img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/></a> 
</div>
<div class="product">
  <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"><br>
  <img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @poi, you can also add `:not()` to style rating image.

```css
/* For Product Image */
.product img[border] {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

/* For Rating Image */
.product img:not([border]) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <a href="#">
    <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true">
  </a>
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="product">
  <a href="#">
    <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true">
  </a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true">
  <br>
  <a hre="#">
    <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true">
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector:

```
.product > img:first-child, .product > a:first-child > img
```

It selects the first *direct* img childs of `.product` *and* all `<img>` tags inside the first direct `a` childs of  `.product`:

```css
img {
    border: solid 2px black;
     }
.product > img:first-child, .product > a:first-child > img {
  border: solid 2px red;
  }
```

```html
      <div class="product">
       <a href="#"><img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"></a><br>
       <img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/>     
      </div>
      <div class="product">
       <a href="#"><img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"></a><br>
       <a href="#"><img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/></a>     
      </div>
      <div class="product">
      <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"><br>
       <a hre="#"><img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"/></a> 
      </div>
      <div class="product">
       <img border="0" src="http://www.vistaview360.com/cameras/images/nikon_images/nikon-d5500-s.jpg" alt="Nikon D5500" width="140" height="140" data-pin-nopin="true"><br>
       <img src ="http://www.vistaview360.com/menuimages/stars-5.jpg"></img>
      </div>
```